# ffmpeg c++/cli wrapper for using in c# . AccessViolationException after call dll function by it's pointer

Tags: ffmpeg, c++-cli

My target is to write a c++/cli wrap arount ffmpeg library, using by importing ffmpeg functions from dll-modules.
Later I will use this interface in c#.
This is my challenge, don't ask me why))

So i've implemented Wrap class, which is listed below:

```
namespace FFMpegWrapLib 
{
    public class Wrap
    {
    private:

    public:
        //wstring libavcodecDllName = "avcodec-56.dll";
        //wstring libavformatDllName = "avformat-56.dll";
        //wstring libswscaleDllName = "swscale-3.dll";
        //wstring libavutilDllName = "avutil-54.dll";

        HMODULE libavcodecDLL;
        HMODULE libavformatDLL; 
        HMODULE libswsscaleDLL;
        HMODULE libavutilDLL;

        AVFormatContext     **pFormatCtx = nullptr;
        AVCodecContext      *pCodecCtxOrig = nullptr;
        AVCodecContext      *pCodecCtx = nullptr;
        AVCodec             **pCodec = nullptr;
        AVFrame             **pFrame = nullptr;
        AVFrame             **pFrameRGB = nullptr;
        AVPacket            *packet = nullptr;
        int                 *frameFinished;
        int                 numBytes;
        uint8_t             *buffer = nullptr;
        struct SwsContext   *sws_ctx = nullptr;

        void                Init();
        void                AVRegisterAll();
        void                Release();
        bool                SaveFrame(const char *pFileName, AVFrame * frame, int w, int h);
        bool                GetStreamInfo();
        int                 FindVideoStream();
        bool                OpenInput(const char* file);
        AVCodec*            FindDecoder();
        AVCodecContext*     AllocContext3();
        bool                CopyContext();
        bool                OpenCodec2();
        AVFrame*            AllocFrame();
        int                 PictureGetSize();
        void*               Alloc(size_t size);
        int                 PictureFill(AVPicture *, const uint8_t *, enum AVPixelFormat, int, int);
        SwsContext*         GetSwsContext(int, int, enum AVPixelFormat, int, int, enum AVPixelFormat, int, SwsFilter *, SwsFilter *, const double *);
        int                 ReadFrame(AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt);
        int                 DecodeVideo2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture, int *got_picture_ptr, const AVPacket *avpkt);
        int                 SwsScale(struct SwsContext *c, const uint8_t *const srcSlice[], const int srcStride[], int srcSliceY, int srcSliceH, uint8_t *const dst[], const int dstStride[]);
        void                PacketFree(AVPacket *pkt);
        void                BufferFree(void *ptr);
        void                FrameFree(AVFrame **frame);
        int                 CodecClose(AVCodecContext *);
        void                CloseInput(AVFormatContext **);
        bool                SeekFrame(AVFormatContext *s, int stream_index, int64_t timestamp, int flags);

        Wrap();
        ~Wrap();

        bool                GetVideoFrame(char* str_in_file, char* str_out_img, uint64_t time);
    };

    public ref class managedWrap
    {
    public:

        managedWrap(){}
        ~managedWrap(){ delete unmanagedWrap; }

        bool GetVideoFrameToFile(char* str_in_file, char* str_out_img, uint64_t time)
        {
            return unmanagedWrap->GetVideoFrame(str_in_file, str_out_img, time);
        }

        static Wrap* unmanagedWrap = new Wrap();
    };
}
```

So the imports to libavcodec and etc. are succesful.
The problem is in AccessViolationException during calling dll func, for example, in OpenInput (i.e. av_open_input in native ffmpeg library)

The OpenInput func code is below:

```
bool FFMpegWrapLib::Wrap::OpenInput(const char* file)
{
    typedef int avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext **, const char *, AVInputFormat *, AVDictionary **);

    avformat_open_input* pavformat_open_input = (avformat_open_input *)GetProcAddress(libavformatDLL, "avformat_open_input");
    if (pavformat_open_input == nullptr)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to find avformat_open_input function address in libavformat module");
        return false;
    }

    //pin_ptr<AVFormatContext *> pinFormatContext = &(new interior_ptr<AVFormatContext *>(pCodecCtx));
    pFormatCtx = new AVFormatContext*;
    //*pFormatCtx = new AVFormatContext;


    int ret = pavformat_open_input(pFormatCtx, file, NULL, NULL); // here it fails

    return ret == 0;
}
```

So the problem, i think, is that class-fields of Wrap class are in secure memory. And ffmpeg works with native memory, initialising pFormatCtx variable by it's address.
Can I avoid this, or it is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, you need to initialise AVFormatContext object.

Good Example:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
```

Bad example:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
```